# Does the angular form object provide a way to get the associated DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS I am currently passing the form object to a function:

```
<a ng-click="clearSearch(searchForm)">clear</a>
```

The goal of this function is to clear an input field (name = `search`).

I can access the search input field like this:

```
searchForm.search
```

What I need to do is something like:

```
searchForm.search.$element[0].focus();
```

However, I cannot see a way to access the form elements (in my contrived example `$element`)

Comment: Can you share contrived HTML to accompany your example code?

Comment: I suppose something like:
`<form name="searchForm">`
  `Search: <input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>`
  `<a ng-click="clearSearch(searchForm)">clear</a>`
`</form>`
@DavidThomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in Angular you generally don't have access to a DOM element from a scope object (although you can get the reverse).

Angular has a pretty strict separation between Controllers and HTML elements, instead they use Directives to manage interaction with DOM elements.

To handle this you can write a directive that is responsible for triggering focus on an input element (in this example the `formFocus` directive). We can then send messages from the Controller to the Directive via the Angular scopes

Here is the example code:

**JavaScript:**

```
myModule.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.clearSearch = function(form){
        // Your current behaviour for clearing the form goes here.
        // ...


        // Broadcast an event down to your child scopes.
        // If anything is interested in your custom 'formFocus'
        // event then it will listen and respond to the event.
        $scope.$broadcast('formFocus');
    };
})
.directive('formFocus', function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            // Add our listener for the 'formFocus' event
            // and write the behaviour to focus on the input element.
            scope.$on('formFocus', function(){
                element[0].focus();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form ng-controller="myController"
      name="searchForm">

    <!-- Add the 'form-focus' directive to the input. -->
    <input type="text" name="search" form-focus>

    <a ng-click="clearSearch(searchForm)">clear</a>
</form>
```

It might seem a bit odd but the separation of the DOM from the Controllers makes things really flexible. For example, your code doesn't need to care which input element will receive focus.

Here's a Fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly_cardinal/bJuS5/1/

Comment: Seems like a strange separation when I can inject `$element` into my controller. 
Events do seem like a good way to do it. I suppose you could take it another level further and add some keys for the `$broadcast` event.

It just seems strange to be able to get the 'form' object, but not be able to drill down to it's $element..

Comment: One of the reasons for the separation is that you shouldn't really know/worry about the element that is related to a form object. In some cases it won't even be an <input> element at all. Using `ngModel` it's possible to make any arbitrary element act like a form element. For example I've used ngModel to implement data binding with a jQueryUI slider which doesn't have a related <input> element.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up storing a local copy of the form element

```
// this = controller
this.searchInputField = $element.find('#search')[0];
```

Then later on I could just go:

```
this.searchInputField.focus();
```

This seemed cleaner than firing and listening to an event every time in this case.